# Can Ethereum blockchain and Bitcoin blockchain integrate with each other thus creating some sort of intermesh of networks?

Tags: blockchain-interoperation

Can Ethereum blockchain and Bitcoin blockchain integrate/interoperate with each other thus creating some sort of intermesh of blockchain networks thus increasing reliability? (Chain of Chains, Blockchains of Blockchains, etc).

If the answer is yes, what is the best way to integrate/intermesh both blockchains together? Atomic APIs?

Blockchain 1.0 - Bitcoin
Blockchain 2.0 - Smart Contracts
Blockchain 3.0 - DApps
Blockchain 4.0 - Chains of Chains? Blockchains of Blockchains?